# Facebook: why my stream.publish attachment image is not found?

Tags: facebook

In my facebook application I'm using this parameters for stream.publish attachment:

```
 attachment: {
    name:        I18n.t("stories." + story_type + ".title", story_data),
    description: I18n.t("stories." + story_type + ".description", story_data),
    href: app_location,
    media: [{
      type: "image",
      src:  document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + story_data.image,
      href: app_location
    }]  
  }
```

Dialog works perfectly, but instead of an image I see the "not found image" icon and the next error message in browser console:

```
GET https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=404638035965159&v=1&size=z&cksum=ee2ef86e90b995d854b34018cdca1cff&src=https%3A%2F%2Fmy_app.com%2Fassets%2Fvillages%2Fimage-22b31ef45b084c7f6de8ee8ee079364c.png 404 (Not Found)
```

The image path looks like:

```
https://my_app.com/assets/villages/image-22b31ef45b084c7f6de8ee8ee079364c.png
```

It's exactly right and if I open this link through my browser - I will get a picture, like all my friends, so it can't be problem of permissions. But why facebook can't get it? The image parameters: 78 x 81 px (up to 90, as it should be), 14,3 K.

Could you please give me some idea, what can be wrong here, why am I getting an error instead of an image? 
I thought, may be, the wrong result of an image is somewhere cached or something like this.

Comment: Facebook sometimes has problems with images referenced via HTTPS. If your image is available via HTTP as well, give that a try.

Comment: Yes. I changed image src from "https://..." to "http://..." and it worked. Thank you, @CBroe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook sometimes has problems with images referenced via HTTPS.

If your image is available via HTTP as well, give that a try.